# How to select second table in sqlalchemy orm_model fastapi python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

```
query = (
        db.query(UserModel)
        .join(UserDocumentModel)
        .join(UserAddressModel, UserAddressModel.user_id == UserModel.id)
        .join(CityModel, CityModel.id == UserAddressModel.city_id)
        .join(StateModel, StateModel.id == CityModel.state_id)
        .join(CountryModel, CountryModel.id == StateModel.country_id)
        .filter(
            UserModel.is_deleted == is_deleted,
            UserAddressModel.is_deleted == 0
        )
    )


results = query.all()
```

If I add `db.query = ( db.query(UserModel, UserAddressModel)...`

got this error:

> raise exc.NoInspectionAvailable( sqlalchemy.exc.NoInspectionAvailable:
> No inspection system is available for object of type <class
> 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>

So I need city name, state name, country name of user; but I don't know how ? How can I get the name without selecting second table ?

Comment: `without selecting second table` Do you meant : UserAddressModel?

Comment: Also,
Can I know, why the table `UserDocumentModel` in join ?

Comment: UserDocument model for get other data so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need city name, state name, country name of user

IF you need to output only these three columns; you can do it using [with_entities](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.with_entities)

Your updated code can be like this :

```
query = (
    db.query(UserModel, UserAddressModel, CityModel, StateModel, CountryModel)
    .join(UserAddressModel, UserModel.id == UserAddressModel.user_id)
    .join(CityModel, CityModel.id == UserAddressModel.city_id)
    .join(StateModel, StateModel.id == CityModel.state_id)
    .join(CountryModel, CountryModel.id == StateModel.country_id)
    .filter(
        UserModel.is_deleted == is_deleted,
        UserAddressModel.is_deleted == 0
    )
    .with_entities(
        CityModel.name.label('city'),
        StateModel.name.label('state'),
        CountryModel.name.label('country')
    )
)

results = query.all()
```

Comment: tx tushar this code is working well tx again